# Ответ в формате JSON

Tags: android, json, kotlin

Я добрался до желаемого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сделал таким образом:

```
val result = JSONObject(data)
        .getJSONObject("response")
        .getJSONObject("GeoObjectCollection")
        .getJSONArray("featureMember")
        .getJSONObject(0)
        .getJSONObject("GeoObject")

adr.text = result.getString("name")
```

Все работает, но чет смущает... внешне странно выглядит. Нужно ли как-то очеловечить это дело, или так сойдет?

Comment: Код соответствует структуре данных, можно в extension function спрятать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [Retrofit'a](https://github.com/square/retrofit) и к нему, допустим [конвертер GSON](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/gson).

Comment: Gson можно пользовать и сам по себе, если что.

Comment: Правда я заюзал не Retrofit + GSON, а Retrofit +Moshi (Moshi is a great JSON library for Kotlin. It understands Kotlin’s non-nullable types and default parameter values.). И Kotlin Coroutine Adapter (call).

Answer (score 2):

Нужно написать такой Deserializer

```
class MyDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<MyModel> {
    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement?,
        typeOfT: Type?,
        context: JsonDeserializationContext?
    ): MyModel{
        val name = json?.asJsonObject?.get("response")?.asBoolean.get("GeoObjectCollection")?.asJsonObject?.get("featureMember")?.asJsonObject?.get("GeoObject")?.asJsonObject?.get("name")?.asString
        return MyModel(name)
    }
}
```

И таким образом прикрутить его к retrofit

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(MyModel::class.java,
                MyDeserializer()
            )
                .create()
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(
                    GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)
                )
```